# How to configure multiple shell steps within Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-scriptler

How can i configure multiple shell steps within Job DSL?
I am configuring a single shell step as below:

```
project / builders / 'hudson.tasks.Shell' {
command 'cd $WORKSPACE/dir1'
}
```

Comment: I found that I should be able to use the shell() method, which can be called multiple times to create multiple shell steps.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-steps-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I should be able to use the shell() method, which can be called multiple times to create multiple shell steps.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-steps-shell